# Laravel 7 passport + Ionic: dudas generales

Tags: laravel, ionic, ionic4, tokens, laravel-7

He implementado la autenticación de usuarios via API con Laravel (7) Passport, pero tengo algunas dudas importantes. El objetivo es poder usarlo como módulo de autenticación en una aplicación móvil construida con Ionic (4).

Después de haber instalado el paquete y de haber seguido las instrucciones básicas en la documentación, he conseguido enviar en la cabecera de una petición el token para que llegue al controlador.

Desde el fichero *ts* hago la petición así:

```
 samplingsRates() {
    var token =  this.authService.token;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': token["token_type"]+" "+token["access_token"]
    });
 
    return this.http.get<SamplingRate>(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/get-sampling-rates', { headers: headers })
    .pipe(
      tap(user => {
        return user;
      })
    )
  }
```

Ahora, en el controlador simplemente obtengo al usuario así:

```
response()->json($request->user());
```

Pero es "tan sencillo" que me da la impresión de que me estoy dejando algo y no lo estoy haciendo bien.

Las dudas que me generó todo esto me hizo intentar "investigar" y probar para asegurarme de que todo esta bien, y esto me acabó generando más incertidumbre:

- Copié directamente un token válido y modifique algunos de los **ultimos carácteres**, lo introduje en la petición y ésta se validó como permitida. Si esto es así, ¿para qué sirve entonces el hash de la última parte del token? (token JWT, Algoritmo RS256).
- Copié directamente un token válido y borré la mayor parte de los últimos carácteres del hash (la tercera parte del token, digamos). Lo introduje en el petición y ésta no se validó. Sin embargo cuando fui a la base de datos, me encontré con que en la tabla *oauth_access_token*, dicho id tenía el campo "revoked" a cero. No debería haber quedado registrada como revocada?
- Otra duda importante es que me fije que cada vez que se produce un logueo, los tokens van quedando registrados en *oauth_access_token*, pero en todos ellos el campo *scopes* está con corchetes vacios. Debería ser de otra forma?

Agradecería que no me lleven a la documentación de Laravel, ya que he pasado varías veces por ahí, leyendo toda ella aunque no enterandome de unas cuantas cosas, como podeís imaginar.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

La implementación de Laravel Passport es bastante sencilla e intuitiva pero para que funcione correctamente debes trabajar con los middlewares que te ofrece laravel para la verificación de los tokens de seguridad:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
   Route::post('cerrar-sesion', 'ApiController@logout');
});
```

Dentro de tu carpeta Routes esta el archivo api.php ahí a las rutas debes colocares el método de verificación, que en el ejemplo que te coloque es para verficar un grupo de rutas " ['middleware' => 'auth:api'] "